# How to restrict \gobble to just one chapter?

Tags: bibliographies, appendices

I have a bibliography chapter and I wanted to remove the extra space and title of the bibliography so I used this code. Gobbletwo was necessary as once the title and space is removed an asterix appears which also has to be removed.

```
\chapter{Bibliography}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{}

\renewcommand{\chapter}{}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@gobbletwo}

\makeatother

\bibliography{Thesis}

The next chapter is the appendix I have this code to give it a letter instead of a number.

\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}

\chapter{APPENDIX A}
```

Each chapter works fine by itself but when both are complied the gobble statement removes the title and chapter heading in the appendix also.

How can I keep gobble to just the bibliography chapter so it dosen't effect the appendix chapter also?

Many thanks this is driving me crazy!

Comment: Welcome! Can we have a complete., small document please? Starting with `\documentclass`? The way you are going about this is not the most straightforward or promising approach, but it is hard to know what you should do without more information. You could restore the command if you saved it first, but that is really not a sane approach. It would be better to configure `\bibliography` to do what you want in the first place. Also, in most classes, `\appendix` is the command to switch to the creation of appendices: no need to mess around with the numbering manually.

Comment: Thankyou for your respone I am using .\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}. Unfortunatly when I use your code I get the error undefined control sequence \notice{*}

Comment: There is no `\notice{*}`. Perhaps you meant `\nocite{*}`? That is just to avoid having to add some citations to make the example work: it adds all entries in the `.bib` file. I had to add stuff to make up the example because you didn't post something complete.

Comment: OMG I'm sorry I confused nocite with notice (fucking dyslexia!) You have know idea how painful ans slow it has been to write this thesis making mistakes like this...Your code works great! I just don't understand why? Is this the line that changes the bibliography format \patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\chapter}{\typeout{patched!}}{\typeout{oh no!}} What's with the oh no!?

Comment: No need to be sorry: it is easy to do when you've been staring at something in frustration ;). We've all been there. Yes. That is the line. It patches the definition of the bibliography environment to use `\chapter` rather than `\chapter*`. It will output 'oh no!' on your console if the patch fails or 'patched!' if it works. You could replace it with something a bit more informative - it is just for tracking/debugging purposes in case you forget you've patched something, or the patch stops working. (Shouldn't happen in this case.)

Comment: Ahh cool I get it now! Thank you so much for your help! You are a king among men sir :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to give a good answer without knowing which class you are using and what you are trying to do. However, if you are using a standard class and are trying to have a bibliography which is a numbered chapter, then try the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\chapter}{\typeout{patched!}}{\typeout{oh no!}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\bibliography{xampl}% standard database for example
\bibliographystyle{plain}% for example

The next chapter is the appendix I have this code to give it a letter instead of a number.

\appendix% don't manage the counter manually!

\chapter{APPENDIX A}
\end{document}
```

This produces several pages including:

[image: numbered biblio]

and:

[image: appendix]

which, if I've understood correctly, is the desired output.

If you want appendices to be called 'Chapter', add

```
\renewcommand*\appendixname{\chaptername}
```

[image: appendix chapter]